# $x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_n\leq M$: Cardinality of Solution Set is $C(M+n, n)$

Tags: probability, combinatorics, inequality, polynomials, discrete-mathematics

Show that the number of solutions in nonnegative integers of the inequality
$$x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_n\leq M,$$
where $M$ is a nonnegative integer, is $C(M+n, n)$.

Comment: There's probably a more elegant way, but: induction?

Comment: Look for a suitable combinatorially equivalent problem for an elegant proof. You'll find one.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** This is the same problem as counting the solutions of $x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_n+x_{n+1}=M$.

**Remark:** We want to distribute any number of candies up to $M$ between $n$ children. We may have some leftovers from the $M$. Give them to me. Then we have distributed exactly $M$ candies between $n+1$ children, one of them an honourary child.

Answer (score 0):

Let's try induction. For $n=2$ the no. of solutions is $\displaystyle \sum_{m=0}^M (m+1)=\frac{M(M+1)}{2}+M+1=\binom{M+2}{2}$. Now, let the no. of solutions for $n=k$ is $\displaystyle \binom{M+k}{k}$. Now, the number of solutions for $n=k+1$ will be $$\sum_{x_{k+1}=0}^M \binom{M-x_{k+1}+k}{k}=\sum_{j=0}^{M}\binom{k+j}{k}=\binom{k+1+M}{k+1}$$ The last step is not difficult to prove and can be proved again by induction or by generating function technique.

Maybe some elegant method is there to prove this, trying to find one.

**EDIT:** I have found this combinatorial proof in [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28combinatorics%29). Hope this is more elegant than the above.

Comment: Find anything? Let me know...